IntelliJ does not find dependency with maven classifier
After updating to IntelliJ 2024.3 I can longer execute JUnit tests, if they have a maven dependency with a <classifier> tag.
If I manually add the jar to the module settings the tests do work again. But this is lost everytime I hit update maven settings.
What I found so far

IntelliJ ignores the <classifier> tag for many years (Please support classifer)
IntelliJ uses the source code of a dependency and not the jar, if it is available in the project.( How to force intelliJ to import a maven dependency with classifier as a "Maven Library" instead of "Intellij Module")

I think the the second point is no longer true when it comes to excute JUnit tests. May be this changed in version 2024.2 or 2024.3?
Any ideas?

Turns out, that this is a known bug: https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-361235/Test-classpath-is-incorrect-when-dependencies-with-classifiers-are-specified

The dependencies you introduced may be in conflict with each other

I don't think so. Maven builds and excutes the tests just fine.
